# org.testng.TestNGException: while trying to execute the tests

Tags: java, android-studio, testng, intellij-15

I have been working on a project using Android Studio since long. Today refactored some code and it started to break,so reverted the changes. Even after reverting the changes whenever I try to debug the code, I am ending up with following an exception :

```
org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 44; Attribute "parallel" with value "none" must have a value from the list "false methods tests classes instances ".
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:325)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:90)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:206)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:177)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:125)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 44; Attribute "parallel" with value "none" must have a value from the list "false methods tests classes instances ".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.validateDTDattribute(XMLDTDValidator.java:1392)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.addDTDDefaultAttrsAndValidate(XMLDTDValidator.java:1311)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1917)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:742)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:380)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:614)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3135)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:172)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:305)
    ... 4 more
```

trying to open the project using `intelliJ` I can get this gone. Any clues on this??

Comment: Do you use a testng.xml? I suppose you are using testng 6.9.10 which check validity of the file.

Comment: updated to 6.9.10.. and yeah there is an xml for the test

Comment: Could you share it? But the problem is parallel param. Replace none by false.

Comment: I am not sure though, is this what you are looking for? `<suite name="SmokeTests" verbose="1" >
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="another.package.TestListener" />
    </listeners>

    <test name="checklist">
        <classes>
            <class name="my.package.SmokeTests" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>` @juherr

Comment: Ok, your file seems good. Do you have the problem when you run the suite via this file or when you run a test from IntelliJ itself (it generate a testng.xml itself in this case)?

Comment: I am trying to execute it using intelliJ. would try using the xml as well and update.

Comment: You can try to override the parallel attribute with false value. I think it is a IntelliJ issue. Maybe you can create an issue on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues and then provide the ticket number here? It will allow me to follow it.

Comment: @juherr https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-149750 raised here..you can check.

Comment: Do you know yet what is setting `parallel` to `none`? To my knowledge, IntelliJ IDEA does not set this so it must be getting set somewhere else. How do you run your test?

Comment: @mfulton26 I am running it using debug option from my class where the  methods are annotated as Test

Comment: @nullpointer Have you changed the run configuration to pass in `parallel`? You might take a look there and if you don't see anything you could try deleting the run/debug configuration and then running again to create a fresh one.

Comment: I would try doing that as well. Though i didn't change that anytime.

Comment: Actually, it looks like IntelliJ does set parallel after all. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29659644/3255152.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98830/discussion-between-mfulton26-and-nullpointer).

Comment: @mfulton26 you got it! Your link says "IntelliJ actually creates an XML file and then uses that when running TestNG. That XML file has parallel="none" inside of it." what is not expected by the testng dtd

Comment: Please downgrade your TestNG version, for me it is working with 6.8.8 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discussion and help from @juherr suggests that solution to this is :

```
Attribute "parallel" with value "none" must have a value from the list "false methods tests classes instances ".
```

TestNG 6.9.10 is now validating the xml file against the [DTD](http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd.php)
The problem is that the default testng.xml template from IntelliJ is setting "parallel"  on suite to "none".
Here is the link to the [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-149750) for the same.

Comment: in fact it seems it is not really the problem. Coud you help us to reproduce the problem (have a look on the bug you opened)?

Comment: I did had a look..would need some time to reproduce the same..since would have to use the 6.9.10 for it..,meaning my tests wouldn't run actually in that case.

Comment: Exactly. This was my problem. I've downgraded the TestNG version to 6.9.9 and it's working well.

Comment: i still prefer `6.9.9` over `6.9.10` @GuillermoCeballos :)

Comment: Guys, anyone knows if this issue was fixed? Any information will be great.

Comment: @EyalSooliman : you can track this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FIDEA-149750

Comment: Thank you. Really helps, I will try to workaround this issue.

Answer (score 3):

update the testng.xml to

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
```

from

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no editable testng.xml file, you can downgrade your testng dependency to 6.9.9.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using/implementing any listener in your class/project then add the annotation `@Listeners` on that class like below:

```
@Listeners(value=SuiteListener.class)
```

e.g.

```
@Listeners(value=ClassName who implemets listener.class)
```

e.g.

```
@Listeners(value=SuiteListener.class)
public class SuiteListener implements ISuiteListener
{
    lines of code / methods in class
}
```

Add below is a code snippet in **testng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
<listeners>
<listener class-name="report.SuiteListener"></listener>
</listeners>

  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="tests.Test1"/>
      <class name="tests.Test2"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->

</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Answer (score -1):

Faced same problem and same exception. Worked for me by removing

```
{parallel="none"}
```

or giving value

```
{parallel="false"}
```

in the `testng.xml` file. Afterward runs fine.