# org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException

Tags: android, unit-testing, appium

I get following error while executing TestNG

```
org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 44; Attribute "parallel" with value "none" must have a value from the list "false methods tests classes instances ".
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:325)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:90)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:206)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:177)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 44; Attribute "parallel" with value "none" must have a value from the list "false methods tests classes instances ".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.validateDTDattribute(XMLDTDValidator.java:1392)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.addDTDDefaultAttrsAndValidate(XMLDTDValidator.java:1311)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1917)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:742)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:379)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3138)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:333)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:172)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:305)
    ... 9 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

After doing some research came to know i have to include testing.xml file in android studio. I want to know in which path this should be added and what is the configuration that needs to be done

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.testng.TestNGException: while trying to execute the tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433163/org-testng-testngexception-while-trying-to-execute-the-tests)

Comment: Can you paste your testNG here